# Problem with the Frobenius norm between a matrix and its approximation using SVD implemented in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

According to Theorem 18.4 of the [IR book](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/18lsi.pdf), the Frobenius error between a matrix and its approximation obtained by zeroing out the k smallest singular values are equal to the largest removed singular value. But, in the following Python code, this Frobenius norm is 1.07 while we expect 1 since the singular values are:

```
array([2.16250096, 1.59438237, 1.27529025, 1.        , 0.39391525])
```

What is the problem?

```
import numpy as np

la = np.linalg

a = np.array([[1,0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1,1,0], [0,0,0,1,0,1]])

svd = la.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
U = svd[0]
S = np.diag(svd[1])
Vt = svd[2]

S[3,3] = 0
S[4,4] = 0

b = np.dot(np.dot(U, S), Vt)
la.norm(a-b)
```

Comment: I've spent a little time looking at it, your code appears correct.  Perhaps there is an error in the book?  There are certainly a number of errors in example 18.4, which you're attempting to follow here.

Comment: @user2699 Agree, the theorem quoted in OP is clearly incorrect. Perhaps they confused the Frobenius and operator norms?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, possibly.  It looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm) has the correct theorem and several proofs.

Comment: @Hossein Good work noticing that discrepancy and asking about it.  It can take a good bit of work to find those sorts of errors in published works.

Comment: In terms of the variables in your code, the correct version of the theorem says that the Frobenius norm of the difference is equal to `np.sqrt((svd[1][-2:]**2).sum())`, or equivalently, `la.norm(svd[1][-2:])`.  That gives `1.07478799052287`, and `la.norm(a-b)` is `1.0747879905228706`.

Comment: Thanks all. Your comments solved the problem.